# Need to Open an Aura component as a popup using a button inside a visual force page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I want to open an Aura Component as a popup with a help of a button click in visual force page. Aura component contains set of records which will display in a table. Can any one help me with this. ?

Also does the Toast messages are supported when the Aura Component is inside an Aura App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [lightning:isUrlAddressable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) and [modals to display in as a pop up](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/)

```
 <aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable">
<aura:attribute name="recordIdfromVF" type="string"/>

    <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <header class="slds-modal__header">
            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                    onclick="{! c.closeModel }"
                                    alternativeText="close"
                                    variant="bare-inverse"
                                    class="slds-modal__close"/>
            <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">About Sfdcmonkey.com</h2>
        </header>
        
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
            <p>

            <!--- ADD YOUR DATA TABLE HERE ---->
            
            </p>
        </div>
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <lightning:button variant="neutral" 
                                label="Cancel"
                                title="Cancel"
                                onclick="{! c.closeModel }"/>
            <lightning:button variant="brand" 
                                label="Like and Close"
                                title="Like and Close"
                                onclick="{! c.likenClose }"/>
        </footer>
    </div>
    </aura:component>
```

Aura controller :

```
    ({
        doAction : function(component, event, helper) {
  
            var recordId=component.get("v.recordIdfromVF");
            alert('Id from VF'+recordId);
        },
    openModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // for Display Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "true"
      component.set("v.isOpen", true);
   },
 
   closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // for Hide/Close Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "Fasle"  
      component.set("v.isOpen", false);
   },
     })
```

in your VF javascript function which you call on button click:

```
<apex:page standardController="account" >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div  id="LightningCompContainer" />
   
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:yourAuracmp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:yourAuracmp", {
            },
            "LightningCompContainer",
            function(component) {
               component.set("v.recordIdfromVF",'{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}');
            });
        });
        
    </script>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: is there in possible way to pass the ID of the record to Aura component with the button click?

Comment: And this will open the component in a new window. Correct? Not as a popup in the same window. I want to open the aura component as a popup in the same window.

Comment: @Hiran did you implement it and try?

Comment: @Hiran I updated the code to pass the ID, please select it as answer if it helps you so it can help anyone in future.

Comment: Yes I Did. And it opens in a new window. Not in the same window as a popup. Thank you for the ID Passing Part.

Comment: @Hiran check the updated code, you can add modal in your Aura component so that when you click button in Vf page, it renders the aura component and that renders the data table in a modal. I have also added functions that you can use to open and close the modal when you want.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try

Comment: @Hiran Mark this as answer if it helped, it does solve your question.

Comment: Do you know a way that I could open this by clicking a Object field "Such as Find College" . Which will make this open in the same window. ?

Comment: You can use any field to open it as long as you call openModal method on click of the Action on the UI.